# Recieving json array and saving in variables. Android

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

So I am receiving a JSON array in an httpresponse. The array consists of the following objects/variables.

> {"sessid":"vxkEXkMBUmBByESRlvaxrxSaFTfhDqd8","session_name":"SESS88cdfb2f1c420898","user":{"uid":"60","name":"abc","theme":"","signature":"","signature_format":"filtered_html","created":"13082976","access":"1386287","login":1386211,"status":"1","timezone":null,"language":"","picture":null,"data":{"mimemail_textonly":0},"roles":{"2":"authenticated user","5":"centre user"},"field_centre_reference":{"und":[{"nid":"256"}]},"field_first_name":{"und":[{"value":"web","format":null,"safe_value":"web"}]},"field_surname":{"und":[{"value":"services","format":null,"safe_value":"services"}]},"bounce_mail_blocked":false,"force_password_change":"0"}}

Now I want to receive all these objects/strings in separate variables. Like i want to store the "sessid" in a variable String session_id. And so on. I can get the first two (i.e. sessid and session_name) in a simple way with the help of the following code.

```
response = client.execute(httppost);

BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String data = handler.handleResponse(response);
jObj = new JSONObject(data);

sessid = jObj.getString("sessid");
Log.d("sessid obj", sessid);
session_name = jObj.getString("session_name");
Log.d("session_name", session_name);
```

But since I am a noob at Android, I don't know how to get the rest of the data to be saved in variables. The upcoming data cannot be saved in a simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
 JSONObject j_user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
 String uid = j_user.getString("uid");
 ...
 //And so on with the rest of the fields
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{ // json object node 
    "sessid": "vxkEXkMBUmBByESRlvaxrxSaFTfhDqd8",
    "session_name": "SESS88cdfb2f1c420898",
    "user": { // json object user 
        "uid": "60", // string 
        "name": "abc",
        "theme": "",
        "signature": "",
        "signature_format": "filtered_html",
        "created": "13082976",
        "access": "1386287",
        "login": 1386211,
        "status": "1",
        "timezone": null,
        "language": "",
        "picture": null,
        "data": { // json object data
            "mimemail_textonly": 0 //string
        },
        ....// rest of the json
```

`{` represents json object node

`[` represents json array node

To parse

```
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(load());
 String sessid = jObj.getString("sessid");
 Log.d("sessid obj", sessid);
 JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
 String uid = user.getString("uid"); 
 Log.d("sessid obj", uid);
```

To parse data

```
 "data": {
        "mimemail_textonly": 0
    },


   JSONObject data= user.getJSONObject("data");
   Log.i(".......",""+data.getString("mimemail_textonly"));
```

To parser field_centre_reference

```
 "field_centre_reference": { // json object field_centre_reference
            "und": [  // json array und
                {        // json  object node 
                    "nid": "256" //string
                }
            ]
        },

  JSONObject field= user.getJSONObject("field_centre_reference");
  JSONArray jr = field.getJSONArray("und");
  JSONObject jb1 = (JSONObject) jr.get(0);
  Log.i(".......",""+jb1.getString("nid"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out JacksonParser library, it provides annotations which make your work so easy. And it is one of fastest parsing libraries... You can have it [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload)

**Edit:**
As an example you can take a look at one of my previous question [JacksonParser databind and core cause "Found duplicate file for APK"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16208032/1171484)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Getting

```
 "user": {
        "uid": "60",

JSONObject obj_user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
String uid = obj_user.getString("uid");

 "user": {
            "uid": "60",
"data": {
            "mimemail_textonly": 0
        }

JSONObject obj_data = jObj.getJSONObject("data");
String mimemail_textonly = obj_user.getString("mimemail_textonly");
JSONObject obj_roles = jObj.getJSONObject("roles");
String two = obj_roles.getString("2");

"field_centre_reference": {
            "und": [
                {
                    "nid": "256"           

JSONObject obj_field_centre_reference = jObj.getJSONObject("field_centre_reference");
JSONArray ary_und = obj_field_centre_reference.getJSONArray("und");
JSONObject objve = ary_und.getJSONObject(0);
String nid= objve.getString("nid");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that the JSON you received is a nested JSON. It is like a Map that one of the value of Map is also a Map.
In your case, there is a JSONObject contains sessid and session_name while is only string, but  the "user" is also a JSONObject, so you can parse it level by level.
For more details, you can read http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html